# Split string is not working in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, string

When using the following code,

```
string text = comboLanguages.SelectedItem.ToString();
string[] split = text.Split("\t", 1);
```

I get an error (below) on the 2nd line.

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments   MainWindow.xaml.cs  46  30

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"\t"` is a string, not a char.

Comment: `string[] split = text.Split(new[] { '\t' }, 1);`, if you want just one item after split.

Comment: Well, this went bad in a hurry.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Agreed its a valid (if simple) mistake that a lot of people make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.Split takes a `char` parameter, not a string. You needed to write:

```
string text = comboLanguages.SelectedItem.ToString();
string[] split = text.Split(new char[] {'\t'}, 1);
```

Comment: is that a ` (next to the 1 button or a ' next to the L button)

Comment: It's an apostrophe. (unshifted double-quote on my keyboard).

Comment: Also called a "single quote" it denotes a character in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the code to:

```
string[] split = text.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, 1);
```

Note that the error is telling you exactly what the problem is.

If you are going to call this code regularly you might want to move the array declaration outside of the call to `Split`.

Comment: Anyone got an idea why this answer got down voted even though it matches the other answer after that one was edited?

Comment: Your answer looks good to me - at least not deserving of -1. I'm not missing something am I?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil Phew. Thanks for the confirmation. I assumed I had missed a glaring error.